# How to call permission dialog again when user clicked don't ask again

Tags: xamarin.forms, permissions, geolocation

Hello guys i make a xamarin.forms app. I need to ask the user to allow app use his location. This is my code:

```
      var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
                if (location == null)
                {
                    location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(new GeolocationRequest
                    {
                        DesiredAccuracy = GeolocationAccuracy.Medium,
                        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
                    }); ;
                }
                if (location == null)
                    LabelLocation.Text = " NO GPS LOCATION";
                else
                    LabelLocation.Text = $"{location.Latitude} {location.Longitude}";
            }
            catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
            {
                // Handle not supported on device exception

                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainMenu());
            }
            catch (FeatureNotEnabledException fneEx)
            {
                // Handle not enabled on device exception

                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainMenu());
            }
            catch (PermissionException pEx)
            {
                // Handle permission exception

                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainMenu());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Unable to get location

                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainMenu());
            }
```

when user click never show again , everytime open the page it goes on `PermissionException` which is ok. But i want to show again the permission dialog because without location can't show data. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer again is, **no you can't**. As you can see in the Requesting permissions [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) (when the user denies a permission and checks that no prompt should be shown from this moment forward):

> Explain to the user that the feature is unavailable because the features requires a permission that the user has denied. At the same time, ***respect the user's decision***. Don't link to system settings in an effort to convince the user to change their decision.

The best practice is to explain in detail to the user **before** you ask for the permission. If the user still decided to deny you this permission, then display a message describing that this particular logic simply won't work. It is *against* the best practices, but if you wish, you can redirect the user to `Settings` where the user can enable the permission. However, I strongly advise you not to do so.

One important side note, again from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#explain):

> If the `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` method returns `PERMISSION_DENIED`, call `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()`. If this method returns `true`, show an educational UI to the user. In this UI, describe why the feature, which the user wants to enable, needs a particular permission.

Also, use `Xamarin.Essentials` for [permission checking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=android). Everything is very well documented there.

P.S. I strongly suggest you read [App permissions best practices](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/usage-notes) where you will find other useful practices from the official Android team.

Comment: i Use Essential Geolocation

Comment: Oh, sorry, by bad. Then everything is fine. Just check the permissions before using it, since the `Permissions` API is more flexible and you can always adjust your flow/UI according to what the user has chosen.